# Can we cascade += operator in php?

Tags: php

Here is what I have

```
$foo += $a
$bar += $a
$baz += $a
$abc += $a
```

Here is something I am looking for

```
$foo += $bar += $baz += $abc += $a
```

Is there any way to achieve this or I have to use the multiline version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increment `$foo`, `$bar`, `$baz` and `$abc` individually.

Comment: So no way to make it a one liner then? Sucks. I dont like this part in the first place but it's a necessary evil in the program.

Answer (score 0):

A bit hack-ish, but it works:

```
array_map(create_function('&$x', '$x += '.$a.';'), array(&$foo, &$bar, &$baz, &$abc));
```

Comment: Hackish indeed, I think this would be pretty bad resources wise (comparatively) because it branches off to different function scopes multiple times. When I thought of the question I had a little more elegant solution in mind :P

Comment: Here's another one, certainly doesn't help the readability of the code: `$foo += ($bar += ($baz += ($abc += $a) - $abc + $a) - $baz + $a) - $bar + $a;` ;) On a more serious note: I don't think you can increase the performance of your code unless there are certain assumptions to be made in regards to your variables (eg. a dependency / ratio you can depend on or something)

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a silly answer but if you really want to keep to one line, for the sake of space, you could just do this:

```
$foo+=$a;$bar+=$a;$baz+=$a;$abc+=$a;
```

Not sure how readable this would be in your program, but it really isn't much different than your original proposal. Otherwise I think your only options are involving `arrays` and/or `loops` and more unnecessary complexity.

Comment: lol from one liner I meant one line for compiler. That would still be 4 lines for the php interpreter. But I agree, no point in making it more complex by using arrays and loops etc.

Comment: Haha ya this does nothing in regard to compiling!